# ¿por que no aparecen los botones, JtextFields y Jlabels en un Jpanel al cual agregue una imagen de fondo?

Tags: java, java-swing

Les dejo el código de la clase del Jpanel y después un extracto del código del JFrame.
Agradezco sus respuestas por anticipado. Dios nos bendiga.

```
  import java.awt.BorderLayout;
  import java.awt.Color;
  import java.awt.Container;
  import java.awt.Dimension;
  import java.awt.FlowLayout;
  import java.awt.Graphics;
  import java.awt.GridLayout;
  import java.awt.Image;
  import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
  import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
  import java.net.URL;
import java.text.Format;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class PanelNorte extends JPanel {
JTextField textoRut;
JTextField textoNombre;
JTextField textoProducto;
JTextField textoCantidad;
JTextField fechaActual;
JTextField fechaEntrega;
JButton    imprimir;
Image      fondo;


public PanelNorte(){

setLayout(new BorderLayout());
setBorder( BorderFactory.createTitledBorder( "Godoy y Asociados" ) );
fondo=new ImageIcon("Salmo.jpg").getImage();



//setBackground(new Color(153,153,255));


JPanel panelCampos=new JPanel();
panelCampos.setOpaque(false);
panelCampos.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1,1,6));


JPanel panelRut = new JPanel( );
panelRut.setLayout( new FlowLayout( FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 0 ) );
JLabel etiquetaRut = new JLabel( "Rut      " );
etiquetaRut.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
etiquetaRut.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,10));
textoRut = new JTextField( );
textoRut.setColumns( 15 );
panelRut.add( etiquetaRut);
panelRut.add( textoRut);
panelRut.setOpaque(false);
panelCampos.add( panelRut );



JPanel panelNombre = new JPanel( );
panelNombre.setLayout( new FlowLayout( FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 0 ) );
JLabel etiquetaNombre = new JLabel( "Nombre   " );
etiquetaNombre.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,10));
etiquetaNombre.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
textoNombre = new JTextField( );
textoNombre.setColumns( 15 );
panelNombre.add( etiquetaNombre );
panelNombre.add( textoNombre );
panelNombre.setOpaque(false);
panelCampos.add( panelNombre );


JPanel panelProducto = new JPanel( );
panelProducto.setLayout( new FlowLayout( FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 0 ) );
JLabel etiquetaProducto = new JLabel( "Producto " );
etiquetaProducto.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
etiquetaProducto.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,10));
textoProducto = new JTextField( );
textoProducto.setColumns( 15 );
panelProducto.add( etiquetaProducto );
panelProducto.add( textoProducto );
panelProducto.setOpaque(false);
panelCampos.add( panelProducto );

JPanel panelCantidad = new JPanel( );
panelCantidad.setLayout( new FlowLayout( FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 0 ) );
JLabel etiquetaCantidad = new JLabel( "Cantidad  " );
etiquetaCantidad.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
etiquetaCantidad.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,10));
textoCantidad= new JTextField( );
textoCantidad.setColumns( 15 );
panelCantidad.add( etiquetaCantidad );
panelCantidad.add( textoCantidad );
panelCantidad.setOpaque(false);
panelCampos.add( panelCantidad );

add(panelCampos,BorderLayout.WEST);

JPanel botonyFecha = new JPanel();
botonyFecha.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,1));
botonyFecha.setOpaque(false);

imprimir = new JButton("Imprimir");
imprimir.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,10));
botonyFecha.add(imprimir);


JLabel etiquetaFecha=new JLabel("Fecha actual");
etiquetaFecha.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
etiquetaFecha.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,10));
botonyFecha.add(etiquetaFecha);

fechaActual=new JTextField();
fechaActual.setEditable(false);
fechaActual.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
fechaActual.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,10));
botonyFecha.add(fechaActual);


JLabel etiquetaFechaEntrega=new JLabel("Fecha Entrega");
etiquetaFechaEntrega.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
etiquetaFechaEntrega.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,10));
botonyFecha.add(etiquetaFechaEntrega);

fechaEntrega=new JTextField();
fechaEntrega.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
fechaEntrega.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,10));
botonyFecha.add(fechaEntrega);



add(botonyFecha,BorderLayout.EAST);



}





public String darRut(){
    return textoRut.getText();
}
public String darNombre(){

    return textoNombre.getText();
}

public String darProducto(){

    return textoProducto.getText();
}
public String darCantidad(){

    return textoCantidad.getText();
}

public JButton darBotonImprimir(){
    return imprimir;
}
public void setFechaActual(java.util.Date fechaActual1){
Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 
fechaActual.setText(formatter.format(fechaActual1));
}
  public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(fondo,0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(),this);
          }
 }
```

Ahora les dejo el extracto de código de la clase del JFrame

```
public class MarcoFinal extends JFrame{
PanelNorte   norte;
PanelCentro  centro;
PanelSur     sur;
public MarcoFinal(){
    setTitle("ERP optica");
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setSize(700,500);
    Container panelContenedor= getContentPane();
    norte=new PanelNorte();
    centro=new PanelCentro();
    sur=new PanelSur();
    panelContenedor.add(norte, BorderLayout.NORTH);
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven solo aparece un JTextField cuando son seis, más un boton

Comment: Intente con super.paintComponents(g); pero no se ven los JLabel y el JButoon

Comment: encontre la solucion gracias de todas maneras

Answer (score 1):

Encontré la solución, gracias de todas maneras, dejo la solución para quien tenga el mismo problema en el futuro y se tope con esta pregunta  tenga una respuesta:
en el metodo paint hay que escribirlo de la siguiente manera.

```
  public void paint(Graphics g){  
      g.drawImage(new 
          g.drawImage(fondo,0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(),this);
          setOpaque(false);
      super.paint(g);  
  }
```